# Django: change project name ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

After changing the name of the project_config file i get this error while trying to makemigration or in general do anything related to python manage.py :

```
(.venv) (base) PS C:\Users\Pablo\Database> python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pablo\Database\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Pablo\Database\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 448, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Pablo\Database\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 93, in wrapped
    saved_locale = translation.get_language()
  File "C:\Users\Pablo\Database\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\__init__.py", line 210, in get_language
    return _trans.get_language()
  File "C:\Users\Pablo\Database\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\translation\__init__.py", line 65, in __getattr__
    if settings.USE_I18N:
  File "C:\Users\Pablo\Database\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 92, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'postgresTest'
```

postgresTest was the name of the project_config file, it is nowhere in my directory,i have gone through every .pyc file and changed every reference in settings, wsgi , urls, etc. The database is hosted in amazon rds and deployed in heroku.
Can someone help me with this?

I attempted to find any reference in a settings module name that maybe causing the attempt at importing postgresTest but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

in wsgi.py there is the standard setup with

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_app.settings')
```

this would give priority to an environment variable with the same name defined on operating system level.
I would check if you have an os environment variable still defined as postgresTest.